# Access to spline tangents in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to draw a spline with tangent handles on each point. Ultimately I'd like to be able to adjust the shape of the curve by editing the incoming and outgoing tangents of each point independently.

Here is a link that illustrates what I'd like to accomplish:

http://www.utdallas.edu/atec/midori/Handouts/tangents.htm

Is this an appropriate use case of D3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question, but definitely yes, this is an appropriate use case for D3.

You'll have a dataset (an array) of objects representing points and handles.

The points will represent your domain mapping to the range (dimensions) of your actual chart container (DOM element). This will produce a linear graph from point to point.

The handles will affect the interpolation between the points. You might want to use a custom [interpolation function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_interpolate) to generate lines produced by dragging handles around. Here's [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3310323) of a simple custom interpolator.

To generate the curves in your interpolators you might want to look at [SVG curve commands documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Curve_commands).